# What would be method to find count which contains only numbers one by one

Tags: java

I have just started my java course so still cannot understand a lot of things, help me out please.
So here is the base code

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main<i> {
    public static void main(String[] args ) {
        System.out.println (" Enter count of digits: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = scanner.nextInt();
        int [] sourceNumber = new int [size];
        System.out.println("Enter your digits with space");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sourceNumber[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            [...]
```

So I have no single idea how to make method to find any count with stepful numbers. Example:
I have counts like: `12405346 534952359 6456934 1234567`
so I need system to find `1234567` and print it out

For example I made method to find a count with munimum same numbers like this:

```
[...]

for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    if (digitsCount[j] > 0)
        differentDigitsCount++;
}
mindifferent = differentDigitsCount;
for (int k = 1; k < size; k++) {
    int differentDigitsCount1 = 0;
    int[] digitsCount1 = new int[10];
    while (sourceNumber[k] != 0) {
        digitsCount1[(int) (sourceNumber[k] % 10)]++;
        sourceNumber[k] /= 10;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (digitsCount1[j] > 0)
           differentDigitsCount1++;
    }
    if (mindifferent <= differentDigitsCount1) {
    } else {
        mindifferent = differentDigitsCount1;
        l = k;
    }
}
System.out.println("Digit with minimum same numbers: " + moimassiv[l]);

[...]
```

This code is huge, but its fine for me now. I just need to make method to find stepful counts

Comment: What is minimum same number? Or do you want to find only number inputs?

Comment: Where is `moimassiv` being modified? I don't see in your code. What is the expected output of your code? I don't understand what `stepful counts`.are.

Comment: Please define `stepful`, do you mean all the digits are consecutive numbers? like `345` or `56789`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to print those numbers whose digits are sorted from smallest to largest. Is that right?

You can convert the number to `String`, then you can get each digit by using `charAt(int index)` method

You can iterate over `sourceNumber` and call `hasSortedNumbers()` for each one to know if its digits are sorted.

```java
for (int number : sourceNumber) {
    String valueOfNumber = String.valueOf(number);
    if (hasSortedNumbers(valueOfNumber)) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

This is the code for `hasSortedNumbers()`

```java
public static boolean hasSortedNumbers(String valueOfNumber) {
    for (int i = 0; i < valueOfNumber.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (valueOfNumber.charAt(i) >= valueOfNumber.charAt(i + 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

<sub>I'm assuming you're going to use this method from main, so it needs to be static, since main is static.</sub>

Basically I'm comparing each digit with the next one, if it turns out that the next one is smaller, it returns false. If not, when it exits the for loop, it returns true.